# Integrating twitter streaming API into a java web application

Tags: java, twitter, jboss

I have a java web app deployed on jboss, this is a war file that produces and consumes json data. I would like to integrate twitter into the application, it would only needs to consume data from twitter so I was thinking the best approach would be to create a twitter account and use the streaming api to consume data.

I like the look of [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html).

How should I build this? should it be as a part of my existing webapp and start it when I deploy my `war` or would it be more appropriate to make an `ear` and add this as an ejb service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using EJB makes sense if you can make use of its advantages: support for automaticly managed transactions, clustering, thread safety, etc. In case of "typical" web application this is usually an overkill.

So I would go with plain web application, if you want easier database integration you might use db stack from Spring Framework.

On the other hand, if you work on the Java EE 6 compliant server, you might pack EJBs inside WAR or use CDI beans to make application as lightweight as possible.

Comment: thanks, that was my main concern that it seemed like overkill when I wasn't really going to take advantage of it